# Easiest way to pop up a progress bar dialog from C++ dll (windows)

Tags: winapi, dll, frameworks

I am writing a dll which is a COM wrapper for another dll (the inner dll) without COM support.  The inner dll performs a lengthy computation and lets the outer dll know how progress is going via a callback function.  The outer dll just makes the functions visible over COM.

However, I need the outer dll to pop up a progress bar dialog (the COM client I'm serving can't do this itself for various reasons).  So how do I go about doing that?  All examples I have seen so far revolve around Win32 apps which have a `WinMain` entry point; what can be done if we're already in a dll call when the dialog is needed?

I'm new to windows GUI programming, so quite out of my depth here.  The existing code is included below - specific suggestions on what to call where would be appreciated.  I'm guessing I may need to fire off a second thread to refresh the progress dialog.

**Inner dll .h file (for implicit linking):**

```
#define INNER_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) 

//create calculation, passing callbacks for warning messages and progress bar
INNER_API Calculation* __stdcall calc_create(...blah...,
    int (__cdecl *set_progressor_callback)(long),
    int (__cdecl *print_warning_callback)(const char*));

INNER_API void __stdcall calc_run(Calculation *c);
```

**Then in the outer dll, the com wrapper, ComWrapperObject.cpp:**

```
    int my_progressor_callback(long progress)
    {
         //set progressor to equal progress, but how?
         return 0;
    }

    STDMETHODIMP ComWrapperObject::do_calculation()
    {
        //fire up progress bar and message window here, but how?

        Calculation *calc = calc_create(...blah..., &my_progressor_callback);
        calc_run(calc);

        //wait for user to dismiss message window, but how?
        return S_OK;
    }
```

Comment: You can show a dialog in a DLL just as you would in an executable. There's no real conceptual difference. But you probably don't want to do that, as Mike says.

Comment: The bigger problem is that your thread will now be a UI thread (now that it has a progress bar) but will not be pumping messages (because calc_creation is hogging the CPU). You will have to split the work between threads.

Answer (score 5):

I'm posting a new answer which is more relevant to your updated question (and in order to be eligible for the bounty). Consider first this minimal source for a regular executable which contains a progress bar:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")
#include "resource.h"
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
    name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
    processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#define PROGRESSBAR_TIMER_ID 1

/*
 * This callback is invoked each time the main window receives a message.
 */
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogFunc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch(uMsg) {
  case WM_INITDIALOG: {
    /*
     * Fire a timer event each second.
     */
    SetTimer(hwndDlg, PROGRESSBAR_TIMER_ID, 1000, NULL);
    break;
  }
  case WM_TIMER: {
    /*
     * Catch the timer event that is fired each second. Increment the progress
     * bar by 10% each time.
     */
    HWND hwndProgressBar = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_PROGRESS1);
    UINT iPos            = SendMessage(hwndProgressBar, PBM_GETPOS, 0, 0);

    /*
     * If the position is already full then kill the timer. Else increment the
     * progress bar.
     */
    if(iPos >= 100) {
      KillTimer(hwndDlg, PROGRESSBAR_TIMER_ID);
    } else {
      SendMessage(hwndProgressBar, PBM_SETPOS, iPos + 10, 0);
    }

    break;
  }
  case WM_CLOSE:
    EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
    break;
  default:
    return FALSE;
  }

  return TRUE;
}

BOOL LaunchGUI(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
  return DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, DialogFunc) == 0;
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  /*
   * Initialise the common controls DLL.
   */
  INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccex;
  iccex.dwSize = sizeof(iccex);
  iccex.dwICC  = ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS | ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES | ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;

  if(!InitCommonControlsEx(&iccex)) {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Problem initialising common controls DLL.", NULL, MB_OK);
    return -1;
  }

  /*
   * Launches the main GUI window.
   */
  LaunchGUI(hInstance);
  return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you like, I can post the relevant `.rc` resource file for this program although the code is mostly for you to gain the correct conceptual understanding. So to quickly summarise, this program:

- Contains a single dialog containing a single progress bar
- Sets a timer to fire each second
- Each time the timer fires, the timer message triggers the progress bar to be updated

Graphically, it looks like this:

[image: Progress Bar]

Your question is how to increment this bar from a DLL instead. What you need to do is to allow some way for the DLL to communicate with the window containing the progress bar. I'm not quite sure how you are loading the DLL, but this is the approach I would take assuming it is done through DLL injection:

- Load/inject the DLL into the target
- Have the DLL export some initialisation routine allowing it to receive information about the injector/client process.
- Use `GetProcAddress` and `CreateRemoteThread` from the client to invoke this initialisation routine.
- In the DLL, use the received information to get the `HWND` of the client.

Concretely, the intialisation routine would look like this:

```
HWND hwndClient = NULL;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
  DWORD dwPID;

  GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwPID);
  if(dwPID == lParam) {
    hwndClient = hwnd;
  }
}

/*
 * This code assumes the client has only one window. Given a PID, it populates
 * a global to hold the window handle associated with the PID.
 */
DWORD WINAPI ReceiveClientPID(LPVOID dwPID)
{
  EnumWindows(EnumProc, (LPARAM)dwPID);
}
```

The client code might be something like this:

```
/*
 * Depending on your method of injection, you should have a handle to the
 * target process as well as a HMODULE of the injected DLL.
 */
void InitDLL(HANDLE hProcess, HMODULE hModule)
{
  FARPROC lpInit  = GetProcAddress(hModule, "ReceiveClientPID");
  HANDLE  hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, NULL,
      (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lpInit, (LPVOID)GetCurrentProcessId(), NULL, NULL);

  if(hThread == NULL) {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Problem calling init routine in DLL", NULL, MB_OK);
  } else {
    CloseHandle(hThread);
  }
}
```

So now you have the `HWND` of the client in the DLL and hence a way for you to do the communication. You can then specify a custom message in the client to change the progress bar:

```
/*
 * The new progress position can be passed in wParam.
 */
#define WM_UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR (WM_APP + 1)
```

Also add the corresponding case in the `DialogFunc` (we can remove the `WM_TIMER` code now because that was only there to demonstrate how to interact with progress bars):

```
case WM_UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR:
  SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_PROGRESS1), PBM_SETPOS, wParam, 0);
  break;
```

And now to trigger changes in the progress bar of the client, the DLL simply has to do:

```
SendMessage(hwndClient, WM_UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR, ..., 0);
```

Note that `WM_UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR` needs to be redefined in the DLL as well.

To fit this all in with your current code:

```
/*
 * Assumed progress is between 0 and 100. Otherwise it has to be
 * normalised so this is the case (or the range of the progress bar
 * in the client has to be changed).
 */
int my_progressor_callback(long progress)
{
     SendMessage(hwndClient, WM_UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR, progress, 0);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for this.  The DLL client is visual lisp for autocad.  Alas the interface is somewhat limited: I'm not sure yet if I have a way of obtaining the HWND of the autocad window that way.  Will this work without a HWND (with the effect that the progress bar will not have a parent window, just be free floating?)

Comment: Nope a parent window needs to be present.

Comment: Shame, so it's really not possible to do this without the HWND?  That rules out this method for me.  Awarding you the bounty for your extensive answer in any case - that has cleared up how these things work a bit - thanks!

Comment: Yes. Controls are by definition child windows.

Answer (score 2):

Since you state that the DLL has no GUI and the client handles all the user interaction, why don't you send the progress information to the client instead and have it displayed there?

If you want to display the dialog in the DLL, you do so in exactly the same way as you would within a regular executable. There is absolutely no difference. If you want the DLL to continue working while it updates the progress bar, you can just kick off a new thread with CreateThread.

If you show some code, we'll be able to help you more directly.

Comment: Alas I can't easily have the client do the progress bar, the client is written in visual lisp and I've found no documentation on how to handle callbacks to that language over COM, which is what it would need.  (Please correct me if there is a way to do this!)  I'll post some code in a bit.

Comment: See my edit - I've added some code; would really appreciate the help if you can!